# Sending email error: The SMTP server > requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated

Tags: powershell, email, outlook

My code previously did not encounter any problem.

The error I get is

> Exception calling "Send" with "1" argument(s): "The SMTP server
> requires a secure con nection or the client was not authenticated. The
> server response was: 5.7.57 SMTP; Cl ient was not authenticated to
> send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM [HK2PR02CA0168.apc
> prd02.prod.outlook.com]" At
> File Path:15 char:17
>
> - $SMTPClient.Send <<<< ($SMTPMessage)
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

I searched online and was only given [this](https://support.solarwinds.com/SuccessCenter/s/article/Client-was-not-authenticated-to-send-anonymous-email-during-MAIL-FROM?language=en_US).

Here's my code

```
$Username  = "myemail@outlook.com" 
$EmailPassword = "password"
$Attachment= "File path"
$EmailTo = "sendto@gmail.com"
$EmailFrom   = "myemail@outlook.com" 
$Subject = "Subject"
$Body= "Body"
$SMTPServer  = "smtp.outlook.com"  
$SMTPMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body) 
$Attachment  = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment($Attachment)
$SMTPMessage.Attachments.Add($Attachment)
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587)
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $EmailPassword) 
$SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage)

ii "another File Path that will be opened"
```

Comment: NOTE: I'm using OUTLOOK

Answer (score 0):

Your credentials are probably wrong.
Check it again.
I messed up there.